# Magento repository on localhost

Tags: install, localhost

I am new to Magento. I have cloned a repository of an existing website on my local machine using Sourcetree. The repository was on Bitbucket. I also have WAMP installed and have imported the database also. How do I launch my website on local machine? Do I need to install Magento 2.0 first and then merge the clone files with it? Any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Point your Apache to the location where the code is at
- Import your db
- Make sure to edit core_config_data - (change your store URL here)
- Clear your var/cache folder

This should point you in the right direction! :)

Comment: Works now but the images are not displaying. Some are but some others are missing. Should I do anything else to map the images right?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Do you have any 404 errors?

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not try to "merge" a Magento 1.X site with Magento 2.X - it won't work!
2. Properly set up your local.xml file to point at your database
3. (optional - but a good idea) scrub all order and customer data from the DB before developing locally
4. Alter proper rows in core_config_data to point to your development domain (configured via your local nginx/apache)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server